# Is there an API for api.ai which can be used to add intents and train the model?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I couldn't find an API for api.ai. The requirement is to add intents and train the model programmatically through an ajax API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, API.AI has a REST-like API that lets you manipulate Intents, Entities, user specific and session Entities, Contexts, and even execute Queries.

You'll need to read details about the developer token and the version string to use, but documentation about getting, creating, updating, and deleting intents, as well as the layout for the intent object, are available at https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/intents

If you're familiar with REST-like APIs, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.